# On-board touchpad and keyboard suddenly stopped working one day on HP Probook 640 G2 running Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: keyboard, touchpad, ubuntu-22.04, hp

My HP ProBook's (running Ubuntu 22.04 LTS) touchpad and keyboard have been unresponsive for a while (along with the trackball button too which comes with probooks, that's also unresponsive).  It was running perfectly till now, and as far as I can remember I haven't done any major updates. The problem started on the login page when yesterday I just couldn't select user and enter password. However my wireless bluetooth mouse and keyboard work perfectly.
I've tried reinstalling the synaptics drivers, but that didn't help.
`xinput list` gives a wayland warning (which seems unrelated) but doesn't show my synaptics pointing device or keyboard in the connected input devices list either.  I entered BIOS, but the touchpad is not there in the built-in device list either.
I've already tried the following solutions (related to config files) but it's not working.
https://askubuntu.com/questions/816982/missing-mouse-touchpad-options-ubuntu-16-04#817358.
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1282260/on-board-keyboard-and-trackpad-not-working-20-04.

My `xinput list` result -

WARNING: running xinput against an Xwayland server. See the xinput man page for details.

```
Virtual core pointer id=2 [master pointer (3)]

↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer id=4 [slave pointer (2)]

↳ xwayland-pointer:16 id=6 [slave pointer (2)]

↳ xwayland-relative-pointer:16 id=7 [slave pointer (2)]

↳ xwayland-pointer-gestures:16 id=8 [slave pointer (2)]

Virtual core keyboard id=3 [master keyboard (2)]

↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard | id=5 [slave keyboard (3)]

↳ xwayland-keyboard:16 | id=9 [slave keyboard (3)]
```

I've been trying various things for hours yet am stuck. Please help.

Comment: Seems like a hardware issue, e.g., a swollen battery pressing on keyboard or connectors. Test by running from USB, e.g., Live Ubuntu. If the keyboard still fails, open the case and look to hardware.